# Как сделать так, чтобы на всех разрешениях выводилась отцентрированная svg картинка с равными отступами?

Tags: html, css, svg, вектор, изображения

В блоке бекграундом задано `svg` изображение. Как сделать так, чтобы выводилась отцентрированная картинка вне зависимости от размеров девайсов, причем отступы при этом сохранялись постоянными и изображение не выходило за границы? [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/55n4u86j/)

```css
.work-scheme {
  background: url(http://a-lot-of-money.ru/wp-content/uploads/work-scheme.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  min-height: 258px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rectangle {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="work-scheme"></div>
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Пока есть возможность регулировать размер `svg` с помощью задания параметров `min-height` в `media-queries`, но это костыль

Comment: background-position: 50% 50%; ?

Comment: @MedvedevDev спасибо, уже лучше, но как сделать так, чтобы отступов не было от соседних блоков на маленьких разрешениях, как здесь https://jsfiddle.net/55n4u86j/ все равно использовать `media-queries` ?

Comment: `background-size: cover;` вместо `background-size: contain;` - если я правильно понял.

Comment: @MedvedevDev то, что вы предлагаете - выглядит так
https://jsfiddle.net/55n4u86j/1/
подвигайте разрешение - замечаете, что при увеличении картинка обрезается и не сохраняются отступы от других блоков?

Comment: Ага, то есть видимо изначально вам нужно было убрать именно "дыры" по бокам, при этом что бы svg была в 100% высоты ... тогда придется переделывать саму svg, посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29259877/7815487

Comment: Хотя учитывая то, что фон - просто заливка цветом, мне кажется было бы проще сделать background-image: url(http://a-lot-of-money.ru/wp-content/uploads/work-scheme.svg); background-color: #F8FAF9; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%; background-size: auto 100%;

Comment: @MedvedevDev нечто подобное, как я записал в ответе ниже?

Comment: нет, я совсем не понял в чем ваша проблема, думал, что в отступах от краев, но видимо это не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что [вот это](https://jsfiddle.net/55n4u86j/7/) решение будет наиболее точным (красные полоски здесь просто как направляющие показывающие отступы между блоками)

```css
.work-scheme-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 258px;
}

.work-scheme {
  background: url(http://a-lot-of-money.ru/wp-content/uploads/work-scheme.svg) top center no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 258px;
  width: 311px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.rectangle {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="work-scheme-wrapper">
  <div class="work-scheme"></div>
</div>
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: По части бекграунда от своих изначальных стилей вы ушли ровно на строчку `background-position: 50% 50%;`, при чем она у вас перекрывает `top center` в вашем `background`, соответственно `top center` можно удалить. Видимо "дыры" по бокам вас не смущают, тогда я бы сказал, что сюда бы ещё добавить background-size: auto 100%; (что бы бекграунд был во всю высоту, а ширина будет изменяться пропорционально)

Comment: @MedvedevDev нет, не смущает, т.к. фон в проекте изначально белый (а в фидле серый), но дабы не смущать сделал тоже белым. А вот насчет `background-size: auto 100%;` не совсем улавливаю - в чем принципиальная разница с ним и без (что с ним, что без здесь отображается все одинаково)
https://jsfiddle.net/55n4u86j/9/

Comment: учитывая свойство `max-height: 100%;` видимо предполагается, что что-то может уменьшить этот блок. Ну предположим этот блок если вписать в блок с высотой `200px`, то этот блок станет тоже `200px` в высоту, тогда без этого параметра svg обрежется сверху и снизу, а с ним, бекграунд подстроится под высоту `100%`

Comment: @MedvedevDev  ок, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
.work-scheme{
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: то, что вы предлагаете - проиллюстрированно здесь jsfiddle.net/55n4u86j/1 подвигайте разрешение - замечаете, что при увеличении картинка обрезается и не сохраняются отступы от других блоков?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить background-size: cover; и паддингами регулировать отступы, таким образом бэкграунд будет занимать все допустимое пространство на всех экранах
Можно еще бэкграунд позиционировать: background-position: [здесь величина в процентах или px]

```css
.work-scheme {
  background: url(http://a-lot-of-money.ru/wp-content/uploads/work-scheme.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 480px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-scheme"></div>
```

Comment: то, что вы предлагаете - выглядит так
https://jsfiddle.net/55n4u86j/1/
подвигайте разрешение - замечаете, что при увеличении картинка обрезается и не сохраняются отступы от других блоков?